# Google Spreadsheet Script to publish chart

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is there a way to publish a chart with a Google spreadsheet script? I dynamically create charts, but need a way to also dynamically publish these charts.

I am referring to the process of publishing a chart from the hidden menu at the top right of a chart. See below.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this functionality doesn't exist in Apps Script, but you can file a feature request on our [issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/entry?template=Feature%20request%20from%20user).

Answer (score -1):

If the dynamic reports are replacing your charts like it did for me I just created a named range on the sheet that held the dynamic data. Then used =importRange to populate the sheet with the chart, then you publish the one time, my data pulls every hour, so my chart updates every hour. Hope it helps.